# Добавить элементы в двумерный массив из другого массива

Tags: python, массивы

Есть два многомерных массива, необходимо в первый массив добавить элементы из 2го массива, при условии "Если их значения в первых столбцах совпадают, то элементы из 2го добавляются к строке 1го массива"
Ниже примеры массивов

```
array1 = [
['41', 2,3,4,5], 
['44', 3,2,5,7], 
['47', 4,5,2,7], 
['52', 5,4,7,8], 
['43', 3,2,6,4], 
['66', 4,4,6,3]
]

array2 = [
['52', 2,1], 
['41', 2,2], 
['43', 4,3], 
['62', 5,6], 
['47', 2,1], 
['44', 5,7]
]
```

Какой массив должен получиться. Т.е. если значение первого столбца 2го массива, есть в 1ом массиве, то в эту строку 1го массива, необходимо добавить оставшиеся элементы строки из 2го массива

```
array = [
['41', 2,3,4,5,2,2], 
['44', 3,2,5,7,5,7], 
['47', 4,5,2,7,2,1], 
['52', 5,4,7,8,2,1], 
['43', 3,2,6,4,4,3], 
['66', 4,4,6,3,None,None]
]
```

**Подскажите, как это можно осуществить? Буду благодарна за минимальный пример осуществления,а не просто текст**

Comment: вряд ли вас интересует буквальный ответ на ваш вопрос («можно ли это осуществить?»). переформулируйте, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) так, чтобы на него можно было дать полноценный ответ

Comment: Проверяете первый элемент каждого списка и если совпадает, добавляете значения. Только вот почему у 66 2 none?

Comment: ну делайте точно так же, как вы делаете это вручну - сравнить первые элементы и добавить, если одинаковые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно с помощью pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

res = pd.DataFrame(array1).set_index(0).join(
    pd.DataFrame(array2).set_index(0),
    how="left", rsuffix="r").reset_index().values.tolist()
```

res:

```
[['41', 2, 3, 4, 5, 2.0, 2.0], ['44', 3, 2, 5, 7, 5.0, 7.0], ['47', 4, 5, 2, 7, 2.0, 1.0], ['52', 5, 4, 7, 8, 2.0, 1.0], ['43', 3, 2, 6, 4, 4.0, 3.0], ['66', 4, 4, 6, 3, nan, nan]]
```